# Issue with Perl Scripts / XML

Tags: xml, perl

I'm fairly new at Perl / XML and i got assign the task to migrate from one server to another some of the perl functionality that we use in our application, i was able to migrate part of it (create and excel file) but i can't get the part to actually parse an excel file done...
I keep getting this error no matter what modules i installed in my perl/site/lib folder..

Software error:
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 3, byte 3 at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cgi-bin\carestreamhealth\importParts_test2test.pl line 255.

I'm at a lost on why this is not working, we have a current instance with the same scripts but running different perl (Active State) and it does work.. Problem with that is that we need to migrate to a windows server 2019 and we are not allow to install active state, we need to use strawberry perl 5.32.1

any help will be appreciate it

Comment: Are you missing a closing tag for '<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Submit" VALUE="Submit Form">'?

Comment: Is not that.. like i said same scripts work in an older version of ActiveState,  Thank you for your feedback. !

Comment: So you have soooooo much irrelevant information in that post, and you don't show the XML that's giving you problems. Please remove what's irrelevant, and provide the file you're having  problems with.

Comment: @ikegami i'm really sorry, to my understanding those are the files that i'm having issues with, i know XML is malformed but i don't understand why the same scripts / data is creating problems running in strawberry perl and i don't have that issue on activestate.

Comment: How should we know? Where's the XML? How did you create it? I reiterate my above comments that you give us a ton of useless info and you're missing all relevant info.

Comment: Before the line ` $twig->parse($resultXML);`, add something like `warn($resultXML);` to dump the XML to your log file, then check that it is well-formed XML.

Comment: @Tobyink This was useful, i didn't actually use the warn but print instead, and i was able to find the root cause of the issue, which basically it wasn't the XML...  The webserver has limited access to the outside world (nobody knew about this just the guy that actually created it) so when it was trying to get data from the actual site where the server is being called upon we were timing out..  We added entries to the server whitelist and everything is working properly. !  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't a malformed XML per say, the issue was that the server wasn't able to reach out to the site where the request was coming from (we added the ip to the server whitelist) and everything is working as expected. Thanks everyone for your comments. !